# Another Javascript callback issue/example

Tags: javascript, callback

I've read a good bit about callbacks, and while I use them for click events and similar, I'm using them without fully understanding them.

I have a simple web app with 3 or 4 html pages, each with its own js page.

I have some global functions that I've placed in a new js page which is referenced by each html page that needs it. I'm using this file, word_background.js, to hold functions that are lengthy and used by multiple pages.

`pullLibrary` is a function, residing in word_background.js, that pulls from my db and processes the results.

I want to call `pullLibrary` from webpageOne.html, make sure it completes, then do more processing in webpageOne.js.

In webpageOne.js I have the following - trying to call `pullLibrary` and, once it is complete, use the results for further work in webpageOne.js.

The code executes `pullLibrary` (in word_background.js) but doesn't "return" to webpageOne.js to continue processing.

I'm assuming I'm missing some critical, essential aspect to callbacks...

I just want to run the `pullLibrary` function (which has ajax calls etc) and, once it is complete, continue with my page setup.

Any explanation/correction appreciated.

This code is in webpageOne.js:

```
pullLibrary(function(){
  console.log('Now processing library...');
  processLibrary();
  updateArrays();
  //Do a bunch more stuff
});
```

----- UPDATE -----

Thank you for the comments...which I think are illuminating my broken mental model for how this should work.

pullLibrary is an ajax function - it pulls from a database and stuffs the results into an array and localStorage.

My expectation is that I can call pullLibrary and, when it is complete, the callback code (in this case anonymous function) will run.

```
function pullLibrary(){   //Values passed from startup() if no data is local
    //Pull data from database and create basic LIBRARY array for further processing in processLibrary sub
console.log("Starting to pull library array in background.js..." + "User: " + localStorage.userID + " License: " + localStorage.licType);

var url1 = baseURL + 'accessComments3.php';
var url2 = '&UserID=' + localStorage.userID + '&LicType=' + localStorage.licType;

//Need global index to produce unique IDs
var idIndex = 0;
var index = 0;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url1,
  data: url2,
  // dataType: 'text',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result){
  // success: function(responseJSON){
    arrLibrary = result;    //store for use on this page
    localStorage.library = JSON.stringify(result);    //Store for use elsewhere
    console.log('Saving to global variable: ') + console.log(arrLibrary);

    //Now mark last update to both sync storage and local storage so access from other browsers will know to pull data from server or just use local arrays (to save resources)
    var timeStamp = Date.now();
    var temp = {};
    temp['lastSave'] = timeStamp;
    // chrome.storage.sync.set(temp, function() {
      console.log('Settings saved');
      localStorage.lastSync = timeStamp;
      console.log('Last update: ' + localStorage.lastSync);

    //Store Group List
      var arrComGroups = $.map(arrLibrary, function(g){return g.commentGroup});
      // console.log('List of comment groups array: ') + console.log(arrComGroups);
      arrComGroups = jQuery.unique( arrComGroups );     //remove dupes
      // console.log('Unique comment groups array: ') + console.log(arrComGroups);

      localStorage.groupList = JSON.stringify(arrComGroups);    //Store list of Comment Groups

    //Create individual arrays for each Comment Groups
      $.each(arrComGroups,function(i,gName){      //Cycle through each group of Comments
        var arrTempGroup = [];    //to hold an array for one comment group
        arrTempGroup = $.grep(arrLibrary, function (row, i){
          return row.commentGroup == gName;
        });

        //Store string version of each Comment Array
        window.localStorage['group_' + gName] = JSON.stringify(arrTempGroup);

        console.log('Creating context menu GROUPS: ' + gName);
      });

    // processLibrary(arrLibrary); //We've pulled the array with all comments - now hand off to processor

  },   //End Success

    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert("Unable to load your library from 11trees' server. Check your internet connection?");
      // var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      // console.log('Error message: ' + err.Message);
  }

});   //End ajax
```

}

Comment: You'll have to show the `pullLibrary()` function.

Comment: Can you publish everything to a server or codepen?

Comment: Is your issue that the anonymous callback function you pass into `pullLibrary()` is never executed? We need to see the code of your `pullLibrary()` function

Comment: Callback functions don't just magically get executed when the main function has finished all its tasks – for one, the `pullLibrary()` function doesn't have any arguments so when you pass the callback function to it, it just gets discarded. At a minimum you need to define the function with something like `function pullLibrary( callback ) { ...` and when it has finished you have to actually call the callback function (`callback();` at the end of the ajax success callback, for example.)

Comment: So if the original call becomes:         
pullLibrary(function(callback){...

And in the success section of pullLibrary I include:
callback();

Then pullLibrary should 'callback' and run the rest of the code in webpageOne.js...?

Except word_background.js throws an error that 'callback is not defined.'

Can you point to an example of what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: No, you need to **define** the function with `function pullLibrary(callback) {...`, not add the argument to the callback itself. There's nothing special about passing functions to other functions. It works just the same way as passing strings or numbers or whatever.

Comment: Ah...I changed pullLibrary() to pullLibrary(callback)...and now the code returns to webpageOne.js...calling back once it is finished? Need to test more to make sure I don't have a synchronous thing going on...and that the code is flexible....so I can pass different "next step" callback functions to the core pullLibrary function...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are tons of "here's how callbacks work" posts all over the internet...but I could never get a crystal clear example for the simplest of cases.

Is the following accurate?

We have two javascript files, one.js and two.js.

In one.js we have a function - lets call it apple() - that includes an Ajax call.

two.js does a lot of processing and listening to a particular html page. It needs data from the apple() ajax call. Other pages are going to use apple(), also, so we don't want to just put it in two.js.

Here's how I now understand callbacks:

**one.js:**

```
function apple(callback_function_name){

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url1,
      data: url2,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){
          //apple processing of result
          callback_function_name();   //This is the important part - whatever function was passed from two.js
      },   //End Success
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      }

    });   //End ajax
} //End apple function
```

** two.js **
This js file has all kinds of listeners etc.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    apple(function(apple_callback){
        //all kinds of stuff that depends on the ajax call completing
        //note that we've passed "apple_callback" as the function callback name...which is stored in the apple function as "callback_function_name".
        //When the ajax call is successful, the callback - in this case, the function in two.js, will be called back...and the additional code will run
        //So the function apple can be called by all sorts of other functions...as long as they include a function name that is passed. Like apple(anothercallback){} and apple(thirdcallback){}
     });   //End apple function
});     //End Document.Ready
```